# QListWidget Add Custom Items in Qt?

Tags: qt, qt4, qlistwidget

How to add 2 Images and Text in QListWidget at run time in Qt?
I want to place one image at the beginning of the  list and one at the end and text should be soon after my first Image.

itemclicked event

```
connect(list, SIGNAL(itemClicked()), this, SLOT(clicked(QListWidgetItem *)));
void MyWidget::clicked(QListWidgetItem *item)
{
   //code

}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have a look at the [`setItemWidget`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/stable/qlistwidget.html#setItemWidget) function. You can design a widget (call it `MyListItemWidget`) that contains two icon labels and a text label, and in its constructor provide the two icons and the text. Then you could add it to your `QListWidget`. Sample code follows:

```
QIcon icon1, icon2; // Load them 
MyListItemWidget *myListItem = new MyListItemWidget(icon1, icon2, "Text between icons");
QListWidgetItem *item = new QListWidgetItem();
ui->listWidget->addItem(item);
ui->listWidget->setItemWidget(item, myListItem );
```

You should also take a look at [`QListView`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/stable/qlistview.html) and [`QItemDelegate`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/stable/qitemdelegate.html) which is the best option for designing and displaying custom list items.

**EDIT CONCERNING YOUR CONNECTION**

When connecting a signal to a slot their signature should match. This means that a slot cannot have more parameters than a signal. From the [signals-slots documentation](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/stable/signalsandslots.html)

> The signals and slots mechanism is type safe: The signature of a
>   signal must match the signature of the receiving slot. (In fact a slot
>   may have a shorter signature than the signal it receives because it
>   can ignore extra arguments.)

This means that your signal must have the `QListWidgetItem *` argument in the connection.

```
connect(list, SIGNAL(itemClicked(QListWidgetItem *)), this, SLOT(clicked(QListWidgetItem *)))
```

Comment: I followed the same approach as suggested by you that works fine but after that when i use itemclicked event on the list it gets fired on double click , it should work on single click.

Comment: How do you handle the `itemClicked` signal? Some code would be helpful

Comment: Sorry I am using the same signature for SIGNAL & SLOT Copy paste Error :(

Comment: Have you debugged it? Are you sure that when a list item is clicked the slot is not called?

Comment: Just to add to you example:  Also add this line `item->setSizeHint(QSize(0,65));` , Otherwise the added item will not be visible, as it happened when i tried using your example.